# tense before "That was until ..."

Tags: tense-agreement, sequence-of-tenses

I am wondering what tense should be used before "That was until" in the following:

> Even though the spice is popular in Asia, it **has remained** largely unknown in the West. That was until a merchant brought it to England in 1868.

Is the present perfect correct in the example?

Comment: In the context of the entire statement, you'd want the past perfect there, **had remained**.

Comment: Could the simple past **remained** be used?

Comment: Those sentences could be rewritten in a number of ways. *Even though the spice is popular in Asia today and had long been popular there, it remained largely unknown in the West until a merchant brought it to England in 1868*.

Comment: *Even though the spice had long been popular in Asia, it remained largely unknown in the West until a merchant brought it to England in 1868.*  *Even though the spice was popular in Asia, it had long remained unknown in the West until a merchant...*

Answer (score 1):

As Tᴚoɯɐuo mentions in his comment, in this context the past perfect "*had* remained*" is expected.

> The spice **had remained** unknown until a merchant brought it to England.

The present perfect would work if you were writing from the perspective of a time right around when the spice was introduced:

> This spice is immensely popular in the Far East, but until now **has remained** largely unknown in Europe.  However I bring Your Majesty a small sample in the hope that it will find favor with your court.